# Why does running this program on 11.10 give a 'GLIBC_2.15 not found' error?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, libraries

I am trying to install Absinthe 2.0.4 on Ubuntu 11.10 on a netbook. When I try to run the install file, this keeps on happening:

> rafael@RafLaptop:~/Desktop/absinthe-linux-2.0.4$ ./absinthe.x86
>   ./absinthe.x86: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./absinthe.x86)

Do I need to upgrade GLIBC? If so, how do I do that? 
Since I'm on a netbook I can't use a LiveCD so I wanted to know if there was a way I could fix this issue without reinstalling my whole OS.

Any explanations about what GLIBC is exactly would be great too since this is a learning experience for me. I know that GLIBC is a part of libc.so.6 and so I tried to run sudo apt-get install libc.so.6 but was told that it was up to date. But GLIBC isn't?

I hope this articulates my problem well, if there are any pieces of missing info or questions to clarity my question, please let me know!

~-~

EDIT/UPDATE:

So after some help on the AskUbuntu chat room from user izx, I have gathered the following information/understanding:

-I need to run this program with Ubuntu 12.04 or recompile it from source
-Upgrading libc on Oneiric to 2.15 while possible, is not an easy task and is not officially supported.

Comment: I added an answer expanding slightly on our discussion in chat, and suggesting that you use a 12.04 LiveUSB to solve this easily and without wasting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: [*Absinthe*](http://greenpois0n.com/2012/05/absinthe-2-0-has-arrived/) is the iOS 5.1 jailbreak tool.

- As tijybba has explained, *libc* (same as *GLIBC*) is the core library required by every single program on your system, including the kernel. For these reasons, it isn't really upgraded very often during the lifetime of a non-LTS release, if at all.
- libc 2.15 shipped by default with Ubuntu 12.04, while Oneiric/11.10 stops at 2.14. No updates to 2.15 are available; while you can certainly download and compile 2.15 yourself, it's relatively complicated and can easily break your system (because it's such a core library).
- For most programs, you could solve this problem by building them from source (where the currently available libc 2.14 would be used), but you *cannot* do this for Absinthe since it looks like they don't make source code available.
- There are ways to make a binary use a specific version or set of libraries (google `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), but they won't work here -- put simply -- because (again!) of how crucial libc is (I tried on 11.10).

Your best option then, is to just create a 12.04 Live-USB, boot from it, install Absinthe, connect your iPhone/iPod/iPad, and jailbreak away.

Answer (score 2):

The required **2.15**  version is not available for **Ubuntu 11.10** as [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric-updates/libc6) and [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/libc6), you will need [Ubuntu 12.04 Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6)  also from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libc6) for that.

Either you will have to build it from source ( not recommended).

[**libc is the C library;**](http://www.linux-m68k.org/faq/glibcinfo.html) basically, it contains all of the system functions that most (if not all) programs need to run on Linux. It's similar to a combination of dos.library and exec.library on Amigas, but it also contains a lot of things that are in the C runtime library (like, for example, ixemul.library or the .lib files included with SAS/C and other compilers for AmigaOS).

You can find its Official [GNU page here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html)